# Javascript regex - Comprimir agrupaciones de caracteres iguales

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy desarrollando un modo de compresión de strings en Javascript que consta de varios pasos. Uno de esos pasos es detectar agrupaciones de caracteres iguales de tres o más caracteres (con dos no tendría sentido hacer esto).

Un string de ejemplo:

`aaabbcccccdeee`

El resultado de comprimir ese string:

`a3bbc5de3`

Puedo obtener ese resultado y revertirlo de la forma clásica (usando for, if, etc). Lo que quiero es lograr esto mediante el uso de expresiones regulares (tanto comprimir como revertir esa compresión).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya está. Solo tenía que googlear un poco más :)

```
let Cadena = 'aaabbcccccdeee'

//Comprimiendo
let Comprimido = Cadena.replace (/(.)\1{2,}/g, (Match, Grupo) => Grupo + Match.length)
console.log (Comprimido)

//Revirtiendo la compresión
let Descomprimido = Comprimido.replace (/(.)(\d+)/g, (Match, Grupo1, Grupo2) => Grupo1.repeat (Grupo2))
console.log (Descomprimido)

//Verificar q la descompresion y la cadena original sean iguales
console.log (Descomprimido === Cadena)
```

Comment: Podés comprimir y descomprimir con el mismo reemplazo y que lo identifique solo ;-)